# Condition Fan out filter in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, innodb

How Condition Fan Out filter in Mysql improves Query Plan Generation(version 5.7)?

What is the drawback of Query Plan generation in older versions of mysql (lesser than 5.7).

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer from below sites.

1. [Part 1](http://mysqlserverteam.com/a-new-dimension-to-mysql-query-optimizations-part-1/)
2. [Part 2](https://mysqlserverteam.com/a-new-dimension-to-mysql-query-optimizations-part-2/)